# Using app.use only in routes that start with /admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

I have several routes, and I need Facebook authentication only in the routes that start with `/admin`:

```
app.get('/admin/dashboard', passport.ensureAuthenticated, .....);
app.get('/admin/dashboard/new/email', passport.ensureAuthenticated, ....);
app.get('/admin/dashboard/new/question', passport.ensureAuthenticated, ....);
app.get('/admin/dashboard/new/answer', passport.ensureAuthenticated, ....);
app.get('/admin/dashboard/new/etc', passport.ensureAuthenticated, ....);
```

If I can't use the `app.use`, is there anyone to call `passport.ensureAuthenticated` repetition in routes that start with `/admin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use):

Path

```
// will match paths starting with /abcd
app.use('/abcd', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```

Path Pattern

```
// will match paths starting with /abcd and /abd
app.use('/abc?d', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})

// will match paths starting with /abcd, /abbcd, /abbbbbcd and so on
app.use('/ab+cd', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})

// will match paths starting with /abcd, /abxcd, /abFOOcd, /abbArcd and so on
app.use('/ab*cd', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})

// will match paths starting with /ad and /abcd
app.use('/a(bc)?d', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```

Regular Expression

```
// will match paths starting with /abc and /xyz
app.use(/\/abc|\/xyz/, function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```

Array

```
// will match paths starting with /abcd, /xyza, /lmn, and /pqr
app.use(['/abcd', '/xyza', /\/lmn|\/pqr/], function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```